# How often do the City or County GIS Parcels data update?

Tags: layers, parcel

How often does the county, or city GIS department update their parcels on their GIS data ? Because I asked, the county GIS parcel data on their interactive online does not mention their date of when the data was last update.

Comment: ...which one? Denver updates every few weeks or sooner, but don't know they stick to a schedule: https://www.denvergov.org/opendata/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-parcels

Comment: No, this question is a broad question so I was asking a question.

Comment: By the way, no it is in southern Colorado.

Comment: it probably depends on the state,city/town this is such a broad question

Comment: This is the sort of information that should be in the associated metadata records

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to contact someone at the city/county/civil division you're interested in to answer this. It totally depends on the budget and personnel they have available to update the data and how often the parcels actually change. It could be weekly, biannually, anywhere in between, nowhere in between, or "whenever we get the money". Quite a few places don't even have GIS data for tax parcels and still rely on PDF scans of paper maps, or the actual paper maps.

Answer (score 1):

One town that I used to work for in Ontario, Canada, would only update their fabric when there were new assessments for tax purposes. The town/city could update their own parcels based on information submitted by developers, consultants and public works. Then we would typically send the new parcels off to the county. This would occur somewhat sporadically and depended on what other projects were on the go and if they took priority. It was then up to the county to update their parcels on their interactive maps. So my answer would be less frequent than weekly and I would variable depending on the size and resources of the county, however this is my Canadian experience. I definitely wouldn't assume they were up to date without having read metadata or contacting the county directly.

Answer (score 1):

From my recent experience from a municipal department(in Finland) it is possible that the situations could be similar. On a project i discovered that some of the publicly published data were not up to date. So i decided to ask around, got some clarification and insights.

1. there are several data access to **internal users** which are up to
   date, these datasets are not available to the public yet
2. as data is generated by different units and departments across agencies, this brings in the time factor to compile and prepare the data for public
   use
3. also there is the issue of processes, resources and people
   assigned for that task specifically. there might not any in place.